# Finding rings of integers and computing class groups

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

To clarify I am not looking for full solutions necessarily, more the general steps to follow.

I'm trying to understand introductory algebraic number theory through some notes and Samuels algebraic theory of numbers. There are few things I'm trying to clarify:

From what I understand, one method to compute class groups is to use Minkowski's theorem and the discriminant to bound the number of possible ideal classes, however in the various examples I've seen I don't fully understand where to go next. I also am confused about the general steps of finding the ring of integers beyond the quadratic field case. For example $\mathbb{Q}(a)$ where $a^3 + a + 1 = 0$.

Is it possible to spell out the steps to compute the class group of e.g. $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{19})$ and the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(a)$?

Here I know that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{19})$'s ring of integers is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{19}]/(x^2 - 19)$ and that the bound is < 5 so I need to consider the ideals (2) and (3):

Then ${\mathbb{O}_{K}}/(2) = \mathbb{F}_{2}[X]/(X^{2} - 1)$

and

${\mathbb{O}_{K}}/(3) = \mathbb{F}_{3}[X]/(X^{2} - 1)$

- but not sure where to go next.

Comment: For class group calculations, see https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/classgpex.pdf.